# Chromedriver not getting detected in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I am Trying to run a selenium script but it is not able to detect the chromedriver can anyone please help me on this when i try to run it it gives me an error stating that chromedriver is not present in the specific path however i have downloaded and kept it on the specific path
below is the snap and code for reference.
[image]

booking.py

```
import booking.constants as const
from selenium import webdriver


class Booking(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self , driver_path = "C:\\chromedriver.exe"):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        super(Booking, self).__init__()

    
    def land_first_page(self):
        self.get(const.BASE_URL)
```

run.py //running this pythonfile in my editor

```
from booking.booking import Booking

inst = Booking()
inst.land_first_page()
```

Comment: Maybe try moving the chromedriver.exe to the Desktop and write the exact path "C:\Users\Desktop\chromedriver.exe".

Comment: getting a new error
 File "c:\Users\Anshul Thakur\Desktop\Selenium Python\Bot\booking\booking.py", line 6
    def __init__(self , driver_path = "C:\Users\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"):
                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
PS C:\Users\Anshul Thakur\Desktop\Selenium Python\Bot>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy your `chromedriver.exe` file to a folder in your current `path`, to display your current path you can use:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Be sure to use the same chromedriver's version as your browser

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Answer (score 1):

Try to insert the whole direction path of where the chromedriver is located, also don't forget to use double slash, "C:\Users\desktop\..." the whole path.

**EDIT**
go and look for the version you are using of google chrome, then check the version of your chromedriver, if they are not the same that's the error, try to install the same chromedriver version of your google chrome version

Comment: Tried that getting the same error which i was getting at first

Comment: @AnshulThakur I edit my answer, hope it helps

Comment: Tried that as well no luck

Answer (score 1):

Copy Chromedriver.exe file and Paste your CODE directory

**Then**

```
import booking.constants as const
from selenium import webdriver

class Booking(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self , driver_path = "chromedriver.exe"):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        super(Booking, self).__init__()


def land_first_page(self):
    self.get(const.BASE_URL
```

[image]

Looks Like. chromedriver.exe file must be same directory where your script file present

Comment: I did not get this you mean to say only put chromedriver.exe instead of the whole path where it is present???

Comment: if you store "chromedriver.exe" in your code folder then no need to mention full path just  mention the chromedriver.exe only

Comment: can you give me a reference or something on how to do that??

Comment: I edited ans and attached image. Now try

Comment: Yes got it Thankyou Kayes Fahim